# Is mongodb fit for sites like stackoverflow?

Tags: mongodb

is mongodb appropriate for sites like stackoverflow?

Comment: The SO clone Shapado http://gitorious.org/shapado uses mongodb. Whether that's an appropriate choice is another matter. Just fyi.

Comment: @Xiaofu damn... you were faster. Just posted this info to my answer. -_-

Comment: Absolutely! I wrote an Open Source StackOverflow-like site **LampCMS.com** (it has many features similar to Quora, and many similar to SO) It's powered by MongoDB and PHP 5.3 and thanks to MongoDB it is blindingly fast! See the demo **http://support.lampcms.com** It's open source so feel free to use it, learn from it or join the dev team.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Put simply: Yes, it could be.**

Let's break down the various pages/features and see how they could be stored/reproduced in MongoDB.

The whole information in this page could be stored in a single document under the collection `questions`. This could include "sub-documents" for each answer to keep the retrieval of this page fast.

**Edit:** as @[beagleguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252253/beagleguy) pointed out, you could hit the document size limit of 4MB quite quickly this way, so it would be better to store answers in separate documents and link them to the question by storing the ObjectIDs in an array.

The `votes` could be stored in a separate collection, with simple links to the question and to the `user` who voted. A [`db.eval()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Using%7B%7Bdb.eval%28%29%7D%7D) call *could* be executed to increment/decrement the vote count directly in the document when a vote is added (though it blocks so wouldn't be very performant), or a [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) call could be made regularly do offset that work. It could work the same way for `favourites`.

Things like the "viewed" numbers, logging user's access times, etc. would generally be handled using a [modifier operation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations) to [increment](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24inc) a counter. Since v1.3 there is a new "Find and Modify" command which can issue an update command when retrieving the document, saving you an extra call.

Any sort of statistical data (such as reputation, badges, unique tags) could be collected using [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) and pushed to specific collections. Things like notifications could be pushed to another collection acting as a job queue, with a number of workers listening for new items in the queue (think badge notifications, new answers since user's last access time, etc).

The Questions page and it's filters could all be handled with capped-collections rather than querying for that data immediately.

Ultimately, YMMV. As with all tools, there are advantages and costs. There are some SO features which would take a lot of work in an RDBMS but could be handled quite simply in Mongo, and vice-versa.

I think the main advantage of Mongo over RDBMSs is the schema-less approach and replication. Changing the schema regularly in a "live" RDMBS-based app can be painful, even impossible if it's heavily used with large amounts of data - those types of ops can lock the tables for far too long. In Mongo, adding new fields is trivial since you may not need to add them to every document. If you do its a relatively quick operation to run a map/reduce to update documents.

As for replication, Mongo has the advantage that the DB doesn't need to be paused to take a snapshot for slaves. Many RDBMSs can't set up replication without this approach, which on large DBs can take the master down for a *long* time (I'm looking at you, MySQL!). This can be a blessing for StackOverflow-type sites, where you need to scale over time - no taking the master down every time you need to add a node.

Comment: wouldn't you hit the 4MB limit on fairly big threads if you embedded the answers within it?

Comment: @beagleguy: probably, yes. Again, all depends on what you're storing. Its probably better to store ObjectIDs of Answer docs in an array in the Question doc.

Comment: 4MB and big threads? Just do some numbers, you could probably store multiple versions of, say, the bible in 4MB. Do you really think _any_ thread will have this many content?

Comment: @halfdan, your comment intrigued me, so I did a quick search and found a plain text version of the King James Bible, which happened to come out to 4.20 MB. Now, I don't doubt that you could probably store SO questions, answers, and comments together in a single document, but I think storing them separately is a much safer approach.

Comment: @Ari Patrick: Alright ;) Nice search. It's definitely a muc hsafer approach, but it's still a lot of space for text.

Comment: @Ari Patrick: safer in what sense? It would either limit your threads to 4 MB, or you would have to give them a second object if they don't fit... If you are getting 4MB out of a db it might be worth checking a value and making a second call if needed... If not you have 2 calls minimum anyway. That being said, some limitations of mongodb are a bit old fashioned if you ask me... Like the 4GB limit on 32bit. I thought we got over that since FAT.

Comment: what about the bounty system ? In this case you need to implement a transaction between two user accounts to transfer reputation

Comment: @ascobol: not necessarily -- one could simply use MapReduce to calculate who is owed what across the whole system, or one could mimic the "transaction" in the business logic... there are many solutions.

Comment: @unpluggd: I think your answer is great, but you may want to revisit your recommendation to store comments separately. There is very slight chance (if at all) that a comment thread will reach the 4MB limit (plus, recent versions of MongoDB have increased this size to 8/16MB). Your answer's size is 2.7 kb. You could store over 1,400 comments of that size in a single document before reaching the 4MB limit.

Comment: The size limit is no longer 4MB, it is now 16MB. So you can stuff almost 4 Bibles inside. ;-) I don't think you need separate collections for the answers, I'd put each question with everything else in a single document.

Comment: Also, in terms of searching, you'd probably want to tokenise all the words of the questions/comments and store them in an array along side the question/comment for search speed (the regex search would be very slow)

Answer (score 5):

I think it is.

You can store the question itself, the answers and the comments on the question + answers as one mongo-document. The max doc size is 4 mb, so no document on stackoverflow will be too big for mongo. I've downloaded the content of stackoverflow (data dump) with bittorrent and I've been able to import this content into mongo.

Importing this data into mongo is not trivial because the dump of stackoverflow consists of multiple xml files and each xml file matches with one relational table, so have to recombine this data into document format.

I've also added the display name + reputation of the OP + answerers + commenters to this document. This does mean that if a user changes his/her displayname you have to update all the documents with his/her userid. There is a price to pay if you denormalize your data. Same if the reputation of a user changes.

The idea is that all the data that you see on a page like this is contained in one mongo-document. You have all the necessary information with one lookup and no joins.

Here you can download the data dump of stackoverflow: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Comment: +1 for info on the dump and how you "ported" it to mongo

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, it's not a great fit, the more complicated your objects get the more an object/document database makes sense.  But if you look at SO, most of it isn't complicated object relationships.

There's a questions table, with however many properties, then a collection of answers...but all these need to be accessed independently depending on which view your coming from, e.g. your activity screen or the question/answer screens.  Since you're accessing it at so many angles and each piece is comparatively simple, a relational model works better.

There are queries running in the background for badges and such, you need to quickly check if you're hitting reputation caps for votes...a lot of relational queries that are simpler in a RDBMS given the complexity of the object model.

*This is of course my opinion, maybe SO's structure is way more complicated than it appears to be*

Comment: or simpler? questions and answers are in the same table.

Comment: I don't think object relationships have to be a lot more complicated for ODBs to make sense. I find that the most important benefit tends to be that the schema is almost non-existant in the DB and can thus be modified more easily, which is a major plus for web development.

Answer (score 1):

With RDBMS for OLTP side of your application and proper caching - it should work gracefully.

---

Actually - there's an [open source stackoverflow clone](http://gitorious.org/shapado/shapado) that uses RoR & MongoDB. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $inc/$dec for vote tracking, so no need to use db.eval

Comment: That's oversimplifying things a little I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good fit.  There are a lot of reasons to use Nonrel databases like MongoDB on sites that function similarly to StackOverflow.  Think about how RDBMs store data to disk and take filesystem block size and similar disk attributes into mind when planning your layout.  I like taking advantage of documents that span multiple filesystem blocks and store lots of related information within itself nice and flattened.  I find that the storage is less spread out and a single block can be written containing a LOT of information where multiple blocks would be written using other solutions.

Answer (score -1):

For me MongoDB is really great for all website that don't need transaction.